# Formatting UTF-8 weird display

Tags: php, utf-8

While I am using `UTF-8` encoding in the `PHP` file, I am getting some weird types of characters

Say like this:

```
"conteÃºdo estÃ¡"
```

How can I display it properly?

The data are being taken from a CSV file which is encoded as `UTF-8` and not plain `ANSII`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```